# create a single regex that creates group matches for dest_ip and dest_port

Tags: regex, splunk

I'm currently working on regex/Splunk challenges for my job. The challenge is to create a single regex that creates group matches for dest_ip and dest_port from this sample log file.

```
> Jan 15 15:16:11 10.0.5.9 Jan 15 15:16:11 ff:ff:00:01 nfc_id=20067 exp_ip=10.0.5.25 input_snmp=2 output_snmp=7 protocol=17 src_ip=43.152.96.179 src_host="unknown" src_port=1049 dest_ip=40.169.38.123 dest_host=unknown dest_port=137 tcp_flag=...... packets_in=131 bytes_in=22078 src_tos=0 dest_tos=0 src_asn=65535 dest_asn=65535 flow_count=1 percent_of_total=10.626 flow_smpl_id=2 t_int=30015  =24520
```

This is the regex that I created, but it seems not to be right. The regex should be extracting the dest_ip and dest_port field

```
^"(?P<dest_ip>.+?)","(?P<dest_port>.+?)"
```

Could someone point me in the right direction or send over some documents that could give me examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current pattern you use named capturing groups, but you don't account for the names `dest_ip` and `dest_port` themselves.

Note that `^` asserts the start of the string and that your example data does not contain `","` which you use in your pattern.

You could use `\S+` to match non whitespace chars after the equal sign and match a non greedy way `.*?` in between to get the named capturing groups for `dest_ip`: and `dest_port`:

```
\bdest_ip=(?P<dest_ip>\S+).*?\bdest_port=(?P<dest_port>\S+)
```

**Explanation**

- `\bdest_ip=` Match literally and use a word boundary to prevent dest_ip being part of a larger word
- `(?P<dest_ip>\S+)` Named capturing group `dest_ip` which captures matching 1+ times a non whitespace character
- `.*?` Match any character except a newline 0+ times non greedy
- `\bdest_port=` Match literally and use a word boundary to prevent dest_port= being part of a larger word
- `(?P<dest_port>\S+)` Named capturing group `dest_port` which captures matching 1+ times a non whitespace character

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oe9Jj2/1)

Comment: That seem to work, but now its grabbing dest_ip=40.169.38.123 dest_host=unknown dest_port=13. the dest_host isnt needed

Comment: @TayvionPayton The `.*?` in between is to get to the first match after that starts with dest_port. The values themselves are in the capturing groups which you can access by name if you want. If you look at the regex demo you will see the groups on the right side. You also might get the separately by using an alternation https://regex101.com/r/5wYNj4/1

Comment: Thanks I see it !!

Comment: And just so i understand correctly `.*?` basically grabs everything in between dest_ip and dest_port. and the groups is extracting the necessary information?

Comment: @TayvionPayton That is correct. have added an explanation to my answer.